# Coin toss probability - With two variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

My question is -
If I toss a fair coin $3$ times,
$X$ - The number of heads in the first two tosses.
$Y$ - The number of heads in the last two tosses.
$Z$ is $Z = X + Y$. What is $V(Z)$?

So I'm thinking if I just should decide that X is the probability to get heads in the first two tosses which is $1/8$, and $1/8$ to get two head in the last two tosses.
and Then to calculate $V(Z) = E(Z) - E(Z^2)$

Comment: That should be $V(Z)=E(Z^2)-E(Z)^2$ ,... but following Preston Lui's guidance is best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Z=T_1+2T_2+T_3$, where $T_i= 1 $ if ith trial is head and $0$ otherwise.

Assume the $V$ refers to variance, the rests is trivial, you should get 1.5 quite easily.

In the case that $V$ is not variance but really the function that you quoted, $E(Z)=2$ and $E(Z^2)=E(T_1^2+4T_2^2+T_3^2+4T_1T_2+2T_1T_3+4T_2T_3)=5$ and $V(Z)=-3$